# Firefox says addon is corrupt even though it can be loaded via about:debugging

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-plugin, xpi

I am trying to write a Firefox addon (adapting a Google Chrome plugin) but I can't get it to install via `about:addons`. I get the error: `This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.`

Installing via `about:debugging` is possible. Similarly, I am also able to run it using `web-ext run`. `web-ext lint` does not show any errors, notices, or warnings.

I have tried installing `.zip` as well as `.xpi`.

I am following the steps mentioned in [Permission requests for extension installation](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/test-permission-requests/).

I have set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `False` as well.

Comment: xpinstall.signatures.required doesn't work in stable Firefox, AFAIK, you need dev/nightly channel.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm using Developer Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, `web-ext build` worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).